# Audit Log records not showing in CRM view

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

On one of our test servers the view in Settings -> Auditing -> Audit Log Management says there are no deletable audit logs available, even though a `select count (*) from AuditBase` in the database returns nearly 90 million records. The user looking at the view has System Administrator privileges. In our other 2 servers (all using the same version of CRM), the view displays records as expected.

What might we do to get the records to show, or alternately to clean up the audit table without using the view?

Answer (score 1):

Strange that the Audit Logs are not appearing in the view inside Dynamics, despite records existing in the database.

It might make sense to open a Microsoft ticket about it.

Or, since your system is on-prem, [here's a discussion](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/121391/manually-purge-auditbase-table/255325) about manually deleting data from the AuditBase table, which is of course highly unsupported.